# Can I simplify the running time analysis of a two-variable algorithm if I know k <= n?

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have the following algorithm:

```
def neat_algorithm(n, k):
    assert k <= n
    assert k > 0

    sum = 0

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            sum += 1

    for i in range(n-k,n):
        sum += 1
```

At first glance, this algorithm looks like its running time is Θ(n^2)+Θ(k), but it will fail unless 1 ≤ k ≤ n, and the worst case would occur if k = n. Since I know these things about k, is it correct to say the worst-case running time is actually Θ(n^2)+Θ(n), or rather just Θ(n^2), or do I need to keep k in the statement of running time?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to say it's Θ(n^2). (This is not just a theoretical concern: some algorithms which work on connected graphs have running time |E| + |V| that are typically quoted as simply |E|, since it bounds |V|.)

Comment: added some code to clarify I didn't mean for the "do things" to have any impact on the looping behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you can simplify Θ(n<sup>2</sup> + k) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), because k ≤ n ≤ n<sup>2</sup>, so the n<sup>2</sup> term dominates.

In general, you should not always substitute k with n in asymptotic notation, even when 0 < k ≤ n. For example, the problem of finding the largest k elements in an unsorted array of length n can be solved in O(n log k) time. If you write O(n log n) instead, then it's still a valid upper bound, but it's a weak upper bound when k is small compared to n (which it often is in real cases). If you are using Θ notation instead of O notation, then Θ(n log n) would actually be incorrect for the case where k is small.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! So, it sounds like I can simplify and get rid of k in my specific example just because k does not influence the asymptotically dominant n term, and I happen to know the remaining terms with k cannot be more asymptotically dominant than the n term, is that right?

Comment: That's right. There might sometimes be two terms like O(n + k^2), for example, where neither term is dominant so you would not be able to simplify, but what you described is correct.